# How to check if a fragment is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a layout that holds 3 fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >




<fragment android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.CarerAwayCarerListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/carerlist"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/carerawaydatetimefragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/carerawayreasonlistfragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```

.

The first fragment on the left will load automatically when this layout loads. I have a Fragment called dateTime Fragment that loads in the middle fragment based on a listview choice in the 1st fragment. The dateTime fragment has an optionsmenu in which i want to hide one of the options based on whether the far right fragment(reasonList Fragment) is showing.

My question is how can i check if the reasonList fragment on the far right is showing from the onPrepareOptionsMenu of the middle DateTime fragment.

I have tried the following but it returns true as the fragment container in the layout is there.

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        View reasonListView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.carerawayreasonlistfragment_container);




    if(reasonListView != null && reasonListView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

        menu.getItem(5).setVisible(false);
    }else{
        menu.getItem(5).setVisible(true);
    }


    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

.

I can't use findFragmentByTag as there is only the reasonList container in the view at that time.

thanks

Comment: @GaneshKumar the problem i have is the middle fragment has an option called update, as does the far right fragment. so when the far right fragment loads i have 2 update options. so i'd like to hide the middle fragment's update when the far right fragment loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved]

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     CarerAwayReasonUpdatefragment reasonListView = (CarerAwayReasonUpdatefragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.carerawayreasonlistfragment_container);
     if(reasonListView == null ) {
         menu.getItem(5).setVisible(true);
     } else {
         menu.getItem(5).setVisible(false);
     }
     super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override **setUserVisibleHint** in the fragment

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29

Comment: Hi, does this not just set the visibility of a particular fragment? I would like to test if a particular fragment is currently visible and then perform some action based on whether it is or not. Sorry if i mis understood how to use your code.

Comment: override setUserVisibleHint into the fragment then you can use isVisibleToUser  to know that you want.

Comment: couldn't he/she just use `getUserVisibleHint()`? why do you need to override it? the functionality already exists